# In maven project how i can specify a relative path to file

Tags: java, css, maven, javafx

In javafx project which create without maven i specify relative path to .css file like

> Main.class.getResource("login.css").toExternalForm()

and it's work.But when i create maven project and use this path i got a runtime exception, but if i use path like

> ./main/java/com/sowl/addStudent.css

or other like this i have exception about resource not found.
And i tried path use Thred

> Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResource("addStudent.css").toExternalForm()

and again have runtime exception.How i can specify path for my javafx.css.StyleManager. In advance,thx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Maven projects, resources go to `src/main/resources`, not `src/main/java` by default.

So if you want to call `Main.class.getResource("login.css")` (relative path), then `login.css` has to be in the same package as Main, but in the resources directory.

If you would call `someClassLoader.getResource("addStudent.css")` or `someClass.getResource("/addStudent.css")` (absolute path), then `addStudent.css` has to be directly in `src/main/resources`.

Comment: Thx!Your answer rescued my laptop from the flight thought the window ))